# Show a function's inverse is injective iff the function is surjective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can anyone help me with this question?

> Let $f:E\to F$. Consider $f^{-1}:\mathcal{P}(F)\to\mathcal{P}(E)$ as a function from $\mathcal{P}(F)$ to $\mathcal{P}(E)$. Show $f^{-1}$ is injective if and only if $f$ is surjective.

Any help would be much appreciated! 
Note: I am brand new to set theory

Comment: There seems to be some basic confusion: given $f\colon E \to F$, I would probably call $f^{-1}\colon P(F) \to P(E)$ the *preimage*, rather than inverse, function. The term *inverse* carries with it connotations that shouldn't be applied here.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f$ were not surjective. Then there is $b \in F$ such that $f(a) \not = b$ for all $a \in E$. That is, there is $b \in F$ such that $f^{-1}(\{ b \})$ is empty. What is another set which has empty preimage?

Suppose $f^{-1}$ were not injective. Then there are $A, B$ distinct such that $f^{-1}(A) = f^{-1}(B)$. Equivalently, $\{ x \in E \vert f(x) \in A \} = \{ x \in E \vert f(x) \in B \}$. But $A \not = B$, so $(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)$ is nonempty; and anything in that set is not hit by $f$.

This demonstrates a useful principle: if you're trying to prove things like "for all…" iff "for all…", then it's often easier to prove the contrapositive both ways. That way you can work with "there exists…" iff "there exists…", which is usually easier because you have some concrete objects to work with.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, but I have a few questions: In your second paragraph you show that if f^(-1) was NOT injective then (A union B) \ (A intersect B) is non empty - but how does this show that IF f^(-1) were in injective , that (A union B) \ (A intersect B) would be empty?

Comment: It doesn't show that $f^{-1}$ injective implies $(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)$ is empty. But it does show that $(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)$ being empty implies that $f^{-1}$ is injective, which is what you actually need here.

Comment: @ThePhysicsStudent I show "not surjective -> not injective" and "not injective -> not surjective". Your question would be showing that "injective -> something".